# How to rotate two objects thus they would point to each other in the 2D plane?

Tags: java, math, libgdx, trigonometry

[image: initial image]
On the initial image, you can see two triangles pointing upwards. By how much in degrees I have to rotate them thus they would point to each other? How can I calculate angles?

Calculating dot product gives only the angle difference between the triangles, but it is not the right value to rotate.

[image]

Comment: This question is not about programming, but about mathematics.

Comment: Eduardo, should I post to a different place?

Comment: The question is basic trigonometry. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the dot products of the wrong vectors. You should dot the direction of each object with the *displacement vector to the other object*. This will give the required angle to rotate through.
[image]
But this alone is not enough - how would you know which *direction* to rotate in, clockwise or anti-clockwise? You can obtain this using the *cross-product*:

`A x B = A.x * B.y - B.x * A.y`

If this quantity is negative, then `A` is anti-clockwise relative to `B`, and vice versa. Therefore if `cross(direction, displacement)` is negative, then rotate clockwise by the calculated angle `θ`, and vice versa.